# Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native@latest - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npx

I've been trying to start a new React Native project but have been facing this issue for a few days, tried searching for it on a lot of forums but couldn't find any solution that works for me.

The commands I've tried:

> `npx react-native init MyApp`

> `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`

> `npx --ignore-existing react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`

Someone mentioned removing react-native-CLI using:

> `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`  and
> `yarn global remove react-native-cli`

Still, no luck. Would be great if anyone could help out.

BTW, I've Node version 14.1.0

[Here is the error from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCrdx.png)

Comment: Did you get any resolve ?. I am facing the same issue !

Comment: I had to uninstall yarn to make it work, `npm uninstall -g yarn`

Comment: @RonAstleLobo and what if he wants to use Yarn instead of NPM?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of node (`14.1.0`) doesn't meet the requirements of the template project.

If you want to stick to node 14, use `^14.15.0`, otherwise switch to node 16 (LTS), and re-run the command.

Comment: In my case npm version is below 7, so addition to this updated npm with 'sudo npm install --global npm@7'

Comment: I got the same error and Google leads me here. I use node 12 and then I switched to node 16 and error gone. This is a weird error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your "C:\Users\YourUser" has a folder named "node_modules" and/or a file named "package.json" and/or a file named "yarn.lock".
If you have them create a new folder (name it whatever you want) and move "node_modules" and/or "package.json" and/or "yarn.lock" to that new folder.
Exit the folder and try to init the project again.

Answer (score 0):

You have yarn in your system and to proceed with react-native need to uninstall yarn

npm: `npm uninstall -g yarn`

brew: `brew uninstall yarn`

tarball: `rm -rf "$HOME/.yarn"`

ubuntu: `sudo apt-get remove yarn && sudo apt-get purge yarn`

centos: `yum remove yarn`

windows: `choco uninstall yarn`

(or go to control panel > add/remove programs and uninstall it from there)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I Faced when I try to run this command in vs code editor integrated terminal, but I try this on power shell it work fine. So, once try in this way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If C:\Users\username isn't intended to be a project, remove any yarn.lock and/or package.json file there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).